# Unable to reach docker container of mysql:8.0

Tags: mysql, docker

I am using a Windows machine, running an image of MySql

I am able to connect to the MySQL DB from the container using the user and password.

Used MySQL:8.0 Image and this docker-compose configuration:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my-secret-pw
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: abcd1234
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
```

But when trying from outside of the container to connect, I am getting a timeout.
I have double checked:

1. Host and port (host taken from the docker inspect network->ipaddress, port 3306)
2. Firewall and network (added rules to allow port 3306)

I can't ping or telnet the container - receiving timeout

His current log status:

> 2023-06-22T00:11:06.926901Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server]
> /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.33'  socket:
> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server -
> GPL.

Check connection script:

```
from MySQLdb import _mysql

# MySQL connection parameters
username = 'user'
password = 'abcd1234'
host = '172.19.0.2'
port = '3306'
database = 'mydatabase'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = _mysql.connect(host=host, user=username,
                        password=password, database=database)

    print(db)
```

What could have I missed?

Comment: Did you specify a port mapping? Could you maybe share some more information, such as your Dockerfile and, for example, your docker-compose.yml or similar (whatever you are using to start the container)?

Comment: @Rob Hi Rob, yes sure I am editing it now. I have used official MySQL:8.0 image, added the docker-compose also.

Comment: did you tried `host='localhost'`? `172.19.0.2` hoping this is your container ip.

Comment: localhost(127.0.0.1) did the job.

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't make it work with the docker IP address but it did work with localhost.

```
from MySQLdb import _mysql

# MySQL connection parameters
username = 'user'
password = 'abcd1234'
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = '3306'
database = 'mydatabase'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = _mysql.connect(host=host, user=username,
                        password=password, database=database)

    print(db)
```